# Compress Image in android

Tags: android, image-resizing, image-compression

I am making an application which takes image from the camera and then email it.

Friends since you know that images from camera may be of too much resolution and in size as well e.g. 2.0MB and more so what i want is to re-size the image in size as well as in resolution so that i could attach that file to the email.

So can anybody give me some code sample or some guidelines to get over my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this to compress BitMap..

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, 160, 160, true);
```

Comment: brother so this will create the bitmap in my required size and then store in my Bitmap object ???

Comment: @sujit Thanks for the peaceful code but it makes the size short but not dimensions. Can you tell me how to maintain aspect ratio ?

Answer (score 4):

try this example

```
public class bitmaptest extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    // load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
           R.drawable.android);

    int width = bitmapOrg.width();
    int height = bitmapOrg.height();
    int newWidth = 200;
    int newHeight = 200;

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // createa matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // rotate the Bitmap
    matrix.postRotate(45);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, 
                      width, height, matrix, true); 

    // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap 
    // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

    // set the Drawable on the ImageView
    imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);

    // center the Image
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

    // add ImageView to the Layout
    linLayout.addView(imageView, 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
            )
    );

    // set LinearLayout as ContentView
    setContentView(linLayout);
}
}
```

you  can try this also

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourimage, 160, 160, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

To resize image try with the following code

```
public static Bitmap resizeBitMapImage1(String filePath, int targetWidth,
            int targetHeight) {
        Bitmap bitMapImage = null;
        // First, get the dimensions of the image
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        double sampleSize = 0;
        // Only scale if we need to
        // (16384 buffer for img processing)
        Boolean scaleByHeight = Math.abs(options.outHeight - targetHeight) >= Math
                .abs(options.outWidth - targetWidth);

        if (options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= 1638) {
            // Load, scaling to smallest power of 2 that'll get it <= desired
            // dimensions
            sampleSize = scaleByHeight ? options.outHeight / targetHeight
                    : options.outWidth / targetWidth;
            sampleSize = (int) Math.pow(2d,
                    Math.floor(Math.log(sampleSize) / Math.log(2d)));
        }

        // Do the actual decoding
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[128];
        while (true) {
            try {
                options.inSampleSize = (int) sampleSize;
                bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

                break;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    sampleSize = sampleSize * 2;
                } catch (Exception ex1) {

                }
            }
        }

        return bitMapImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this image compression example from
http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/

```
public String compressImage(String imageUri) {
     String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

        float maxHeight = 816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 612.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {               imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);               actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;             } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filename;
  }
private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }


public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height/ (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;      }       final float totalPixels = width * height;       final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;       while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```